# How to pass data between 3 or more activities in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I am trying to create a project that gets your phone number on MainActivity, passes it to the VerifyPhone activity which sends you the authentication code to your phone.

I could only pass the phone number value from MainActivity to VerifyPhone activity but could not get it to a String value to pass it to my THIRD activity.

What I tried to do:

MainActivity information passage:

```
String complete_phone_num = "+" + phone_num;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VerifyPhoneActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("phonenumber", complete_phone_num);
            startActivity(intent);
```

VerifyPhone Activity:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String phonenumber = bundle.getString("phonenumber");
```

then I tried to pass `phonenumber` to `ProfileActivity`:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        intent.putExtra("phoneNum", phonenumber);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Unfortunately it doesn't recognize the variable `phonenumber` outside of OnCreate.

I am looking to pass the phone number to other activities so I can store it in my database and use it for statements so it will be organized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i believe you are trying to create new intent and start it outside of oncreate methond, but you are declaring the variable phonenumber inside of it, so it cant be reached outside of its scope, try declaring it as a private field of a activity class and initialize it in onCreate() method, then you will be able to use it.

Comment: No, I am declaring the phonenumber on my VerifyPhone activity(second one) inside the OnCreate method and trying to pass phonenumber to ProfileActivity(third one)

Comment: I believe what Madonabulia said is most likely correct Ada, you most likely have a scope issue where your third activity does not know about your variable. So I would do has he suggests and try declare your variable outside of the onCreate methods, but then populate it inside your onCreate method, it should then hopefully be accessible to the third method.

Answer (score 1):

As @Code-Apprentice said. I also think you need to add a variable outside the Method and set the value of the extra to this variable.

Something like this:

```
String phonenumber = "";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
phonenumber = bundle.getString("phonenumber");

public void someOtherMethod(){
Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra("phoneNum", phonenumber);
                    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Another solution would be to pass the String as a parameter to a specific method.

Comment: still makes my application crash - https://pastebin.com/FbK4caEp

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra("phoneNum", phonenumber);
```

Sure that you didn't make a typo and are checking for "phoneNum" in ProfileActivity?

If not what do you mean by outside of OnCreate? are you trying to access it as a member variable? In case you do you should wait for OnCreate in ProfileActivity to finish setting the value first using the method that you already use in VerifyPhone

Comment: Yeah I have checked that, it isn't the case. 
as I said: Unfortunately it doesn't recognize the variable phonenumber outside of OnCreate.

Comment: what about the second part of my answer? Are you trying to access it before onCreate()? Because the value should be retrieved and used only after/in onCreate

Comment: Can I declare "phonenumber" on second activity outside of OnCreate? If so, how? Because it caused the crash of my application.

Comment: Just declare it as a variable in the class like class ProfileActivity{
String phonenumber;
onCreate(){}
}
And then check if phonenumber==null before using it, and set the value using getIntent in oncreate

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately it doesn't recognize the variable phonenumber outside of OnCreate.

You need to declare `phonenumber` as a private field of the activity. I suggest that you learn about instance fields in Java classes.

Comment: I am just doing it as a final year project for High School, I just need basic understanding, I would thank you if you can explain it to me.

Comment: @Ada I have given you the terms you can use to google to get the basic understanding from a Java or Android tutorial.